# I need a apps script to copy and email files

Tags: google-apps-script

I need a apps script to make a copy of a folder in google drive along with the google docs inside it then email those copies to someone. I've tried looking up bits and pieces of code to make this work but none of the ones I try have worked.

Here's the script I've previously come up with

```
function myFunction() {{// make copy 
doc = DocumentApp.makeCopy('example');
}
                {                                                           
GmailApp.sendEmail("example_recipient@example.com", "test", "Just a test");
               }                                        
}
```

Comment: You need to make an attempt to get something working. You can show us your work, and explain what you want it to do and how it isn't doing that. We won't do your work for you.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I added my previous work to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function emailDrive() {
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById("id"); 
  var files=folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  var bA=[];
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    bA.push(file.getBlob());
  }
  if(bA.length>0) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail('example_recipient@example.com','RE: files you requested', 'Please review and respond',{attachments:bA} )
  }
}
```

Comment: I ran this and it seems to work but one thing, I get a "Missing exponent. (line 3, file "Code")" error at the top of my page am I doing something wrong with the script?

Comment: Did you replace the ID perameter with the folder ID that you want to get the files out of?

Comment: I did replace it in the getFolderById line but do I need to fill it out in the if(id) or function area of the script?

Comment: I changed the code a little to make it easier for you to use.  Just put the id in this line `var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(id);` and you should by good to go.  Before I had it so that you could use it as a parameter to the function.  Remember you have to put quotes around the id.  It's a string

Comment: Thank you, seems to work so far. if I have any problems I'll let you know.